# Integration test with DBUnit IO Exception Java

Tags: java, ios, spring

I write an integration test on a SpringFramework Controller but i have some issues with data base. I do not undertand why dbunit can not locate my schema.sql file. I tried to use absolute path but it did not work too.

**ControllerTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@DatabaseSetup(value = "login.xml")
public class LoginControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = org.h2.Driver.class.getName();
    private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1";
    private static final String SCHEMA_PATH = "schema.sql";
    private static final String USER = "sa";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "";

    @BeforeClass
    public static void createSchema() throws Exception {
        RunScript.execute(JDBC_URL, USER, PASSWORD, SCHEMA_PATH, null, false);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.xmlConfigSetup("loginControllerTest-context.xml").build();
        IDataSet dataSet = readDataSet();
        cleanlyInsert(dataSet);
    }

    private IDataSet readDataSet() throws Exception {
        return new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(new File("login.xml"));
    }

    private void cleanlyInsert(IDataSet dataSet) throws Exception {
        IDatabaseTester databaseTester = new JdbcDatabaseTester(JDBC_DRIVER, JDBC_URL, USER, PASSWORD);
        databaseTester.setSetUpOperation(DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT);
        databaseTester.setDataSet(dataSet);
        databaseTester.onSetup();
    }

    @Test
    @ExpectedDatabase("login.xml")
    public void testShowForm() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/login")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(view().name("/login"))
                .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WebContent/j/login.jsp"))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("od", nullValue())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("email", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("username", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("hostname", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("pass", isEmptyOrNullString())));
    }
}
```

**loginControllerTest-context**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.profiles.controller.test" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:login" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Stack Trace**

```
org.h2.message.DbException: IO Exception: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: schema.sql (The system cannot find the file specified)"; "schema.sql" [90031-191]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convertIOException(DbException.java:330)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:333)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.execute(RunScript.java:303)
    at com.profiles.controller.test.LoginControllerTest.createSchema(LoginControllerTest.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runBefores(ClassRoadie.java:49)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:36)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: schema.sql (The system cannot find the file specified)"; "schema.sql" [90031-191]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: schema.sql (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FilePathDisk.newInputStream(FilePathDisk.java:321)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.newInputStream(FileUtils.java:218)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:185)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:328)
    ... 15 more
```

**SOLUTION**

i have fix my problem when i move sql file to a folder under test source folder and set the path to - **classpath:/sql/schema.sql**

Comment: Where is the file located on your filesystem?

Comment: Where is `schema.sql` file located? Is it under `resources` directory?

Comment: @Jens The file is located in the package where is LoginControllerTest

Comment: @user2004685 do i have to move it to a resources directory ?

Comment: try `this.getClass().getResource("schema.sql").toExternalForm();`

Comment: @Jens this can not work in a static context like this here.

Comment: Then use `LoginControllerTest.getResource("schema.sql").toExternalForm(); `

Comment: @Jens LoginControllerTest do not have a static method called getResource. I do not understand what you ?